# file input can't be blank to be saved into MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, express

when trying to save a registry into MongoDB, node won't save it unless an image is selected.
I want this parameter to be optional, not required.

```
router.post("/", upload.single("image"), async (req, res) => {
  const post = new Post({
    title: req.body.title,
    category: req.body.category,
    content: req.body.content,
    video: req.body.video,
    **image: req.file.filename,**
  });
  try {
    const savedPost = await post.save();
    res.redirect("/");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

here is the mongodb schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    min: 3,
    max: 255,
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  category: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
  },
  video: {
    type: String,
  },
  uploadDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: () => Date.now(),
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Post", PostSchema);
```

here is the error:
image: req.file.filename,
^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filename')

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the `Post` schema

Comment: I'm assuming you're using mongoose in this case? What does your schema look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to read the property `filename` on `req.file`, which is null. So essentially you are writing `null.filename` which of course is incorrect.

So you should check wether there is a file before trying to read the `filename` property. You can do this by replacing `image: req.file.filename` with the following:

```js
image: req.file ? req.file.filename : null
```

This way you first check wether `req.file` isn't null. If it isn't, we assign `req.file.filename` to image. If it is, we assign `null` to image.